# Wcf webservice not working after migration to https

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, web-config

My react app was working fine when we were using wcf service over http. We decided to implement SSL for our website and now that service is not working. Tried many web config settings but its not working. Read many docs on microsoft site but can not solve this problem.

Webconfig

```
    <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="largeMessage" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
        <security mode="Transport"/>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="Service.EService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviors">
      <endpoint address="" contract="Service.IEService" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeMessage" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
      <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding" />
    </service>
  </services>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? What errors do you get? At a first glance I would change `<security mode="None"/>` to `<security mode="Transport"/>`.

Comment: Changed it to Transport still giving error 'An application error occurred on the server'

Comment: Try WCF tracing by adding an app.config to get more details. See [Configuring Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing)

Comment: Do you set `httpsGetEnabled="true" `to allow https requests.
`<behaviors><serviceBehaviors><behavior><serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/><serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/></behavior></serviceBehaviors></behaviors>` https://geeksarray.com/blog/configure-iis-for-wcf-service-with-ssl-and-transport-secuirty

Answer (score 0):

1. Put httpsGetEnabled="true"
2. Making security mode="Transport"

3 Removing line endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding" />

After making these changes I am now be able to get the service running on https.